# Trig functions in complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, trigonometry, singularity

Can someone explain to me how trig functions work in the complex plane? I'm trying to show that $f(z) = \cos(1-\frac{1}{z})$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$, and part of doing that requires I find a sequence $z_n$ so that when $z = z_n$, $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} f(z)=\infty$. Originally I assumed $\cos(z)$ would never approach $\infty$, as it is bounded between 1 and -1, however my thinking was clearly with real variables, as I was informed that $coz(z)$ can in fact approach infinity in the complex plane. I'm trying to understand when this will happen, any information to help my understanding is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should approach this using the following formula, which is valid for all complex numbers $z$

$$\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$

We also have the cooresponding formula for sine

$$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

These can both be proven by using $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(x)$ and solving for the respective quantities.

As pointed out by Rob Israel, these two formulas are sometimes used to *define* the sine and claims functions on the complex plane. The other way that they are sometimes defined is via their Taylor polynomials.

Comment: These formulas are often used as the **definitions** of $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$ for complex $z$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good point! I'll add that information to my answer.

Comment: @StellaBiderman: I tried to fix the misspelled "corresponding" but it won't let me change just two characters - so you'll have to do it :-)

Comment: @Nick thanks for the correction!

Comment: So if I use this formula, when will $\cos(z)$ tend to infinity? As $iz$ tends to infinity?

Comment: If $z = x + i y$ for real $x$ and $y$, $|\cos(z)|^2 = \cos(x)^2 + \sinh(y)^2$, so this goes to $\infty$ on any path where $|y| \to \infty$.

Comment: ^^ This relationship can be established using the fact that the formula for $\sinh(z)$ and $\cosh(z)$ are identical to the above formulae for $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ except with the $i$'s removed.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the deeper answer to the "why" of why it will happen is first off to point out that one *cannot* and *should not* expect that the behavior of at least analytic complex functions should mirror that on the real number line.

In particular, one very important theorem of complex analysis is that *any non-constant entire function is unbounded* (more often-stated converse: a bounded entire function is constant), where "entire" means it is complex differentiable everywhere. The same is *not* true for real-valued functions, as $\cos$ and $\sin$ illustrate.

(There is another interesting theorem in the same vein which says that an *injective entire function is linear*, which means that almost all the "nicest" complex functions are *not invertible*!)

Thus if we are to extend $\cos$ and $\sin$ in *any* way to the complex plane that preserves their differentiability they *must be unbounded* and thus there *must* be some way to approach $\infty$ under them following some suitable path in the plane (which can be discretized to a sequence). It does not matter how we do it -- as long as we want to be able to take a derivative everywhere this *must* hold. It's even better than that -- if we want to take $\cos$ and $\sin$ as agreeing with their real number equivalents but are willing to admit only an *isolated* set of nondifferentiability points (i.e. just a few scattered points), we will actually get them to be differentiable everywhere and so they will still be unbounded.